# Oracle find a picture's most common colors

Tags: image, oracle, colors, multimedia, segment

I'm new at oracle multimedia/intermedia and currently I'm dealing with the oracle docs. I would like to 'color profile' an image that stored in oracle ORDImage. I saw there is SI_COLOR and SI_HISTOGRAM but it maybe not the one i need.

Here is an example: There is an image let's say a landscape, mainly green and blue. And somehow i would like to extract this information like RGB(000,200,000) RGB(000,000,200) and bulid up a mapping DB table with the main colors and try to match the image. 65%Green and 25% blue or something like that.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime i have the solution.

If a picture is stored in ORDIMAGE, i have to convert it first to BLOB then to SI_STILLIMAGE.
Then i can use the SI_COLORHISTOGRAM that contains rgb,frequencie pairs, easy to find to top N most common color
Then i can use this topN color list for a picture to match it to some basic color :)